# Facebook photo privacy problem

Tags: privacy, facebook-like, facebook-photos

My photo album is limited to friends only, but still photos can be viewed in section "abc's photo" but not in album section.

Photos are not shared by anyone but friends of friends can view it.

Comment: So what’s your question?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you don't also have "Friends of those tagged" selected.

From the drop-down that allows you to choose Only Me | Friends | Custom etc as the album privacy, click on Custom and you will see this dialog:-

[image]

As you can see, by default "Friends of those tagged" is selected.

Another selection in the drop-down "These people or lists" instead of choosing Friends, you can choose "Friends of Friends". Make sure you haven't got that selected instead of just "Friends".